# Windows Phone 8 AdControl AdException?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, ads

I've been testing a new Windows Phone 8 app for the last couple of weeks. I haven't yet published it to the Store yet, so I've only tested my `AdControls` with test values (i.e. "test_client" and "Image480_80").

I noticed the other day as soon as I launch my app, I see the `AdControl` for a second, and then it disappears. No error is thrown on the app's interface, but in the Output window I can see the following exception:

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.Advertising.Shared.AdException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.DLL and wasn't handled before
>   a managed/native boundary

Here is the stack trace:

> at
>   Microsoft.Advertising.Shared.AdvertisementFactory.CreateFromResponse(String
>   response, AdDownloadCompleteCallback adDownloadCompleteCallback)\r\n
>   at Microsoft.Advertising.Shared.AdPlacement.CreateAdvertisement(Byte[]
>   bytes)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Advertising.Shared.AdPlacement.AdRequestComplete(IWebRequestWrapper
>   request)

Here is my code which adds the `AdControl` to my `Grid`:

```
    AdControl adControl = new AdControl("test_client", "Image480_80", true);

    adControl.Width = 480;
    adControl.Height = 80;

    adControl.ErrorOccurred += AdUnit_ErrorOccurred;

    MyGrid.Children.Add(adControl);

    Grid.SetRow(adControl, 4);
    Grid.SetColumn(adControl, 4);
```

This **was** working fine up until a few days ago, so I'm not sure if the code needs to change but is there anything else I can check? I saw an article that said to make sure I've got the required capabilities in my WMAppManifest.xml file. Here's what I've got currently:

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_AUDIO" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER" />
</Capabilities>
```

Does anyone know of anything else I can check - or know what I may be doing wrong? I'm really stumped. If there's anything else I can post from my Exception object (in addition to the stack trace above) please let me know, although I didn't see anything that hinted at a possible problem.

**UPDATE:**

I can also confirm that using my actual ApplicationID and AdUnitID in place of the test values that the exact same thing happens. Has anyone else experience this?

**UPDATE 2:**

I've been emailing back and forth with PubCenter Support, and they've apparently been able to replicate the problem because the analyst helping me (Support Analyst II) has now engaged the engineering team to look into the problem. There is no ETA on a resolution but they said using my actual ApplicationID and AdUnitID *should* work when testing on an actual device (although I already confirmed it does not work in my emulator).

**UPDATE 3:**

I'm still waiting to hear back from PubCenter Support, but I have now confirmed that Ads DO WORK successfully if I use the real ApplicationID and AdUnitID. Previously, I thought this didn't work, but it appears it only doesn't work when running in the emulator - on the device itself, they work fine. So it is only test ads that don't seem to work, and since that's the case, I'm not too worried about it.

**UPDATE 4 (SOLUTION):**

OK - After weeks of back and forth with PubCenter Support I finally have a solution, although I'm pretty sure it was an issue on their end that is now resolved. I had created a very simple test solution which demonstrated my problem that I sent to them and they finally concluded that this:

```
AdControl adControl = new AdControl("Test_client", "Image480_80", true);
```

Needed to be this:

```
AdControl adControl = new AdControl("test_client", "Image480_80", true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this:

```
AdControl adControl = new AdControl("Test_client", "Image480_80", true);
```

Needed to be this (note the lowercase "t" in `test_client`):

```
AdControl adControl = new AdControl("test_client", "Image480_80", true);
```

Who would have thought?

Answer (score 1):

To find out more specific error information, you can inspect the [AdErrorEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-aderroreventargs-class(v=msads.20).aspx) passed to the [AdControl.ErrorOccurred event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-adcontrol-silverlight-erroroccurred-event(v=msads.20).aspx) you've already registered. If it's still not clear from that information, please add the error/error code to your question.

The reason I've seen this exception show up is that there are no ads to display (ie you've specified a too narrow selection of ads to display and there are no matching ones available), but that should in that case be clear when you view the error.

Comment: Thank you. The only clue I can find inside `AdErrorEventArgs` is "  Message "An unexpected error occurred during call to the ad source (Name: CNTX)." And just to clarify, since I'm only testing, would having no ads to display affect me? Previously, when it was working, I would always see the exact same "Microsoft Advertising" ad.

Comment: FWIW - it says "ServerSideError" for the ErrorCode property of AdErrorEventArgs. Do you think it's a PubCenter problem? I've seen other posts about it happening sporadically, but this has been EVERY time for the last few days. Also, I don't think it should have anything to do with my selection of ads since I'm just using test values.

Comment: @lhan16 Agreed, not a very helpful message :-/ Could you try debugging with Debug/Exceptions/Common Language Runtime Exceptions/Thrown checked and see what the actual underlying exception thrown is? To your second question, I've seen the error about no ads available when running test mode, it may be related to a bad network connection though.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Debug/Exceptions/Common Language Runtime Exceptions/Thrown checked" - could you tell me how to turn those on/check them?

Comment: @lhan16 In Visual Studio, go to the Debug menu, choose "Exceptions" and check the "Thrown" checkbox on the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" row. Now that you mention it, I'm not sure which editions of Visual Studio has that feature. Let me know if you can't find it.

Comment: OK thanks. I've got it checked now but I'm not seeing anything happen differently. I still only see the exception thrown in the output window.

Comment: @lhan16 Hm, with the option checked, the debugger should halt when the exception is thrown and not just log it. Since I can't run the emulator on this machine I'll have to get back to you tomorrow when I can test it myself.

Comment: I also tried creating a brand new Windows Phone application, and trying to add a testing advertisement, and the exact same thing happens. So I don't think it's related to my project, but maybe the PubCenter API?

Comment: @lhan16 Yes, a quick test project gives me the same effect, so seems server related. Didn't have the chance to debug further than "it fails for me too".

Comment: OK, thank you! I'm glad it's not just me. I've emailed PubCenter support so I will update back here if I hear anything back!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The ads in my WP7.5 app work in both the emulator and the phone. When I upgrade my app to WP8 the ads stop working. So, I added a second ad provider control to my app and made it so that if MS ad control gets an error it hides and displays the 2nd ad from a different company.

Comment: May I ask what the second provider is? Also, are you located in the United States? I haven't heard back if it's a "location" issue.

Comment: the second provider is NAX. yes, I am in US.